# Error: Projects created at console.firebase.google.com must use the new Firebase Authentication SDKs available from firebase.google.com/docs/auth/

Tags: javascript, google-maps, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new new to Firebase and Google Maps API. I want to integrate Firebase in Google Map for real-time heatmap as in doc. whenever I clicked on the map, the data gets added in Firebase database, but the data or the heatmap isn't shown.

```
  function initAuthentication(onAuthSuccess) {
    firebase.authAnonymously(function(error, authData) {
      if (error) {
        console.log('Login Failed!', error);
      } else {
        data.sender = authData.uid;
        onAuthSuccess();
      }
    }, {remember: 'sessionOnly'}); 
   }
```

The error from console is like:

```
Login Failed! Error: Projects created at console.firebase.google.com must use the new Firebase Authentication SDKs available from firebase.google.com/docs/auth/
    at firebase.js:163
    at XMLHttpRequest.e.onreadystatechange (firebase.js:147)
```

I have a script for Firebase as this from Google docs:

```
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.3.2/firebase.js"></script>
```

i tried changing the script to

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.6.2/firebase.js"></script>
```

and I also changed the rules in Firebase as:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You will need to do more that just change the `<script>` version: https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-web

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing this:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.6.0/firebase.js"></script>
```

And change the code for anonymous authentication:

```
function initAuthentication(onAuthSuccess) {
    firebase.auth().signInAnonymously().catch(function(error) {
      if (error) {
                console.log('Login Failed!', error);
              } else {
                data.sender = authData.uid;
                onAuthSuccess();
              }
    });
  }
```

And you also need to add Firebase to your project, see the following link:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup